# IOS Push Notification with fcm

Tags: apple-push-notifications

How to Solve this error...

```
{"multicast_id":6860363857346799604,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

Comment: First, try to explain your problem more clearly with description, sample code, and then the above response

Answer (score 0):

You must get the token device id from Fcm first then send to it.